# User defined Windows shortcut for menu in pages

Tags: c++, visual-c++, win32gui

I have to create a page using visual studio c++ with different menus having shortcuts (key accelerator).The shortcut should be like the way we have in windows notepad eg.(alt + f for files,alt + e for edit) etc.I want to know how to implement my own alt+key shortcut for the menu items that i have in my page.Please help.

Comment: any link if you all could provide?

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to define an ACCELERATORS resource in your resource file (*.rc). The [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) give this example of an accelerator table.

```
1 ACCELERATORS
{
    "^C",  IDDCLEAR         ; control C
    "K",   IDDCLEAR         ; shift K
    "k",   IDDELLIPSE, ALT  ; alt k
    98,    IDDRECT, ASCII   ; b
    66,    IDDSTAR, ASCII   ; B (shift b)
    "g",   IDDRECT          ; g
    "G",   IDDSTAR          ; G (shift G)
    VK_F1, IDDCLEAR, VIRTKEY                ; F1
    VK_F1, IDDSTAR, CONTROL, VIRTKEY        ; control F1
    VK_F1, IDDELLIPSE, SHIFT, VIRTKEY       ; shift F1
    VK_F1, IDDRECT, ALT, VIRTKEY            ; alt F1
    VK_F2, IDDCLEAR, ALT, SHIFT, VIRTKEY    ; alt shift F2
    VK_F2, IDDSTAR, CONTROL, SHIFT, VIRTKEY ; ctrl shift F2
    VK_F2, IDDRECT, ALT, CONTROL, VIRTKEY   ; alt control F2
}
```

You'll compile the resource file (with RC, the Microsoft resource compiler) and link the resulting *.res file with your application.

Next, in your `WinMain`, call `LoadAccelerators` (see the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the syntax) with the identifier of your resource table so the application has access to it. For the table above, you could do

```
HACCEL hAccel = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, 1);
```

where `hInstance` is the `HINSTANCE` of your application, and the `1` is the identifier of the table.

Finally, call `TranslateAccelerator` (again, see the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the syntax) in your message loop, after `GetMessage`, to be able to handle accelerator messages. Again, in this example, you could do

```
TranslateAccelerator(hwnd, hAccel, &msg);
```

where `hwnd` is the `HWND` of your main window and `msg` is the `MSG` structure defined for your main window.

If you do all this correctly, your application should receive a message via WM_COMMAND whenever an accelerator event occurs, and the `wParam` field of the message will contain the identifier of the key event that was triggered (the `IDD*` constants in the example table).